# Do monthly sales of a retail shop have a unit-root?

Tags: time-series, small-sample, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

Simple question to understand if by nature monthly sales from a retail shop on the high street are likely to have a unit-root in its timeseries or not?

Comment: Hi Alejandro, could you elaborate a bit more? Is there a particular reason that has led you to think that this could be the case?

Comment: Hi kk68, I have a data set of 100k shops where I have tested for stationarity using an ADF test, and the null-hypothesis of a unit-root is not always rejected.

Comment: Thanks. I asked because the original question seems to be an economic theory question. It might be helpful to ask it on another platform, such as https://economics.stackexchange.com.

However, if your question is, "What could be the potential statistical reasons for failing to reject the ADF null hypothesis in some of the 100k cases I am analyzing", it might be more beneficial to provide additional details about your specific case. For example, what you mentioned (a dataset of 100k shops) could be relevant in understanding and addressing the issue.

Comment: You might often reasonably expect monthly sales from a retail shop to show seasonal effects.  Allowing for that, you would need some reason to believe it would be trend-stationary rather than a unit root.

Comment: Thank you @Henry. You are probably right. My data is a year's worth of observation, and it's hard to include a seasonal pattern as a result, this is why I may be finding a unit root despite trying to include a trend.

Comment: @kk68 - you make a good point, as ultimately I want my model to reflect the underlying economic drivers. Thank you.

Comment: @AlejandroLeno I also wonder if it may be worth considering the possibility of false negatives (Type II error), given that you are running 100k tests (if I got it right) and doing some adjustments to the p-value threshold.

Comment: kk68's point about false negatives is a relevant one. 1 year worth of monthly data means 12 observations. That is a tiny sample, and the test will have low power. It will not be able to reject $H_0$ of presence of a unit root unless the deviation from $H_0$ is huge.

Comment: I simulated 100k ADF tests ( `tseries::adf.test(ts, alternative = "stationary" `)) on the same number of white noise series composed of 12 observations each – `rnorm(12, mean = 0, sd = 1)` – and got a rate of false negative (p-value > 0.05) equal to about 90%. If this is correct, the test is unreliable with so few observations, as per @RichardHardy comment.

Answer (score 2):

kk68's point about false negatives is a relevant one. 1 year worth of monthly data means 12 observations. That is a tiny sample, and the test will have low power. It will not be able to reject $H_0$  of presence of a unit root unless the deviation from $H_0$ is huge. kk68's comment about simulation provides additional evidence for this.

Also, the distribution of the test statistic under $H_0$ from which the $p$-values are derived may be problematic in such small samples. If the software implementation uses an asymptotic distribution, it may provide a poor approximation to the distribution in a small sample.

Keywords: **small sample**, **low power**.